# Can this trigonometric equation be solved exactly or approximately?

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find a solution for $\alpha$ that satisfies the following equation for $i=1,2,...,N$

$$\frac{2i}{K} = \sin(2 \alpha i) \left(\frac{\frac{\cos(k-1)\alpha}{2}-\frac{\cos(k+1)\alpha}{2}}{1- \cos(\alpha)}\right)$$

Where k and K are positive constants.

Any suggestions about how I may go about this, either exactly or approximately using a computer?

Comment: Why do you expect a solution to exist? Are there extra conditions on $k$, $K$, and $N$? For example, if we fix $K=10$, $k=1$, $N=2$ then [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x%3A+4%2F10+%3D+sin%284x%29%281%2F2%29%281%2F2-cos%282x%29%29%281%2F%281-cos+x%29%29+and+2%2F10+%3D+sin%282x%29%281%2F2%29%281%2F2-cos%282x%29%29%281%2F%281-cos+x%29%29) says there is no solution.

Comment: I'd be amazed if there was some clever way to find a closed-form solution. And I don't see that the equation has any special properties that we can leverage. So, the best you can do is toss the problem to a numerical root-finder. But you can't do that until you fix $K$ and $k$ and $i$. It would be wise to do some graphing, first, to understand the behaviour of the function better. But, to do this, you again need to fix $K$ and $k$ and $i$.  As Tom implied, Mathematica could be used for both the graphing and the root-finding.

Comment: The equation can be re-written as $$2i \tan(\alpha/2) = - K\; \sin(k\alpha)\sin(2i\alpha)$$ Working with it in that form may be helpful. (It would certainly be easier to type into Wolfram Alpha!)

Comment: To be clear: Do you want a *single* $\alpha$ that works for *all* $i$? Or does every $i$ get its own $\alpha$? In the first case, if $N$ is at least $2$, it's not too hard to show that one of $\alpha$, $2\alpha$, $k\alpha$ must be an integer multiple of $\pi$. In the latter case, I'd re-write the equation I gave above in complex-exponential form (writing "$j$" for your "$i$", to avoid confusion with $\sqrt{-1}$); this will provide a polynomial equation in $e^{i\alpha}$ that can be solved numerically.